# How to Position Popover in Ionic 3 Project running in Windows?

Tags: ionic3

I am trying to display an Ionic popover in Windows 8.1. I’m using

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/2 with the popover interface. However, the popover always starts from left side of the control (ion-label). I could not find any documentation on how I can make it start from right side of the control. Can you please help?

This is how I’m displaying the popover.

`<ion-item no-lines>
                    <ion-label><span *ngIf="!isEditTopic">{{'Choose' | translate}}</span> {{'Topic' | translate}}:</ion-label>
                    <ion-select interface="popover" [(ngModel)]="newTopic.TOPIC_ID" placeholder="Select" disabled="{{isEditTopic}}">
                        <ion-option *ngFor="let topic of topics" value="{{topic.TOPIC_ID}}">
                            {{topic.TOPIC_NAME}}
                        </ion-option>
                    </ion-select>
                </ion-item>`

Screen Before displaying the Popover
[image]

Screen After displaying the Popover
[image]

Comment: try this solution, given for similar question on SO [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524197/how-to-position-a-popover-in-ionic-2)