# Ionic 4 popover appearing off screen

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an Ionic 4 Popover on a button on the bottom of the screen. When I click the button to open the popover, it appears off-screen underneath...

.html

```
<div class="TabBarItem" (click)="popover($event)">
  <label>Tab Item</label>
</div>
```

.ts

```
   function popover(ev) {

    this.popoverController
                .create({
                  component: PopoverComponent,
                  event: ev,
                  translucent: true,
                })
                .then(el => {
                  el.present();
                });
    }
```

Result...

[image]

Is there a way to fix this, or manually reposition it?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524197/how-to-position-a-popover-in-ionic-2
If not, try to provide a Stackblitz example replicating the issue :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do is add `<ion-content>` to my popover component. This fixed the issue.